# Sending JSON response from NodeJS/Express

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

sorry for the n00b question I have been kinda stuck so I was hoping you guys could put me in the right direction.

I am making an app that is retrieving data by NODEJS from a REST API. (This is a success and works).

I then have a listen URL (my own API) in express that I invoke by going to the browser http://localhost/api or by using POSTMAN. So far so good, I see in the console (NODE Console) that my request gets handled perfectly as I see the JSON response, however, I would also like to see the JSON response in the browser or POSTMAN as JSON Response, not just the console I know I am missing something in my (simple) code but I am just starting out.... Please help me out here is my code.

```
var express = require("express"); 
var app = express();
const request = require('request');

const options = {  
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Accept-Charset': 'utf-8',
    }
};

app.get("/api", function(req, res)  { 
    request(options, function(err, res, body) {  
    var json = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(json);
    });
    res.send(request.json)
    });

app.listen(3000, function() {  
    console.log("My API is running...");
});

module.exports = app;
```

Much appreciated!

Comment: what should request.json be?

Comment: No request in particular ;-) I just hit the /api url without any request parameters. I wanted to send the response from my request (the API i consume) via res.send(request.json) but that does not return me the body of the request that was what i was trying to figure out how to do. So in short. My request to the JSON API works and I want that request outputted as soon as I hit my own API via http://localhost:3000/api -> invoke request to other api -> 1) retrieve data, 2) console log that data BUT 3) also show it in browser as JSON. 3 does not seem to work, 1 and 2 work

Comment: maybe res.json(json) ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Much thanks to ProgXx, turned out I used the same res and response names. Here is the final code. Much thanks ProgXx

```
var express = require("express"); 
var app = express();
const request = require('request');

const options = {  
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Accept-Charset': 'utf-8',
        'User-Agent': 'my-reddit-client'
    }
};

app.get("/api", function(req, res)  { 
        request(options, function(err, output, body) {  
        var json = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(json); // Logging the output within the request function
        res.json(json) //then returning the response.. The request.json is empty over here
}); //closing the request function

});

app.listen(3000, function() {  
    console.log("My API is running...");
});

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 7):

To send json response from express server to the frontend use `res.json(request.json)` instead of `res.send(request.json)`.

```
app.get("/api", function(req, res)  { 
  request(options, function(err, res, body) {  
    var json = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(json); // Logging the output within the request function
  }); //closing the request function
  res.send(request.json) //then returning the response.. The request.json is empty over here
});
```

Try doing this

```
app.get("/api", function(req, res)  { 
  request(options, function(err, response, body) {  
    var json = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(json); // Logging the output within the request function
    res.json(request.json) //then returning the response.. The request.json is empty over here
  }); //closing the request function      
});
```

Comment: With your code It returns 0 in the browser and postman -- returns blank so I am missing something more I'd say :)

Comment: I don't think you are sending the response from correct location.Move res.json() inside the request function. As you are returning the values before even you have gotten the response. See the answer, for the updated code.

Comment: Okay.. you need to change the parameter name in the `request` function. Both have the same name `res`

Comment: Aha makes sense ;) Much appreciated!!!!! I will change my final code now so others don't make this n00by mistake.

Comment: Happy to help :)